# How to validate if form has at least one not empty input?

Tags: angularjs, forms

Just like in the title: I am wondering how I can validate, if my form has at least one input which is not empty - and then change the submit button to enabled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
     <form name="myForm">
     <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstname">
      <input type="text" ng-model="user.secondname">
      <button type="button" ng-click="checkIsEmpty()" ng-disabled="!user">SUBMIT
      </button>
     </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.user = {};

    $scope.checkIsEmpty = function(){
      return angular.equals({}, $scope.user);
    }
}
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/nq1eyj1v/128/

Comment: Yeah, that approach works only if user obejct has not been defined before, however, I am looking for approach that will take advantage of validators, rather than basing on one object.

Comment: Your answer is not universal, and works only if user is not defined before.

Comment: @uksz I have updated my answer. What is your feedback for this.?

Comment: Its still not universal. What if user has some other parameters defined before, then, it is not just a plain blank object.

Comment: I understood. But than can also be managed. You can post your code sample.